# GTX 550 ti and new monitor doesn't show the maximum resolution

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

I have a new monitor (`DELL S3220DF`) that supports a maximum of 2560x1440.

And I have a `NVidia GTX 550 ti` that also supports a maximum resolution of 2560x1600.
I use a DVI->HDMI cable.

So this both should work.

But the highest resolutions I see are 1920x1440 and 2560x1080.

I loaded the latest driver and I can see that the monitor is detected and reports the highest resolution. What can I do?

Comment: I think you need a dvi dual link cable to support that resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. (May be the terms are different, because I use a German OS)
I added a custom resolution in the NVidia Control panel.

- I opened the NVidia Control Panel.
- Select Display -> Resolution
- In the resolutions you can select Customize
- I added 2560x1440 but I must select a different Timing.

Now a perfect display as wanted.